# Make a program that generates a new .exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exe

Does anyone know if it is possible to make a program (written in C++) generate a .exe-file? For example, let's say a user wants to have a generated .exe that executes a web browser. In the program he/she clicks on Firefox, IE, or Chrome from a set of checkboxes and presses generate. The idea is now that this new generated exe-file now will start the seleced web browser each time the user starts the generated exe.

The program is planned to be written as a Windows Application in VS 2010.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Isn't shortcut sufficient?

Comment: @nhahtdh: That's just an example.

Comment: It would be infinitely easier to generate a shortcut instead.

Comment: @Araw: It'd be better if you give a more motivating example. Otherwise, people would take it as your goal and answer the question based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to this would probably be to have an already compiled executable, but with the name of the actual program you want to run empty. Then patch the file to put the proper path to the program you want to run.

But like I said in my comment, if you just want to start another program it would be much easier to just create a shortcut instead.

Comment: Thank you for your provided answer. I'll try this solution (patch an already compiled executable).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, programs that generate executables are called compilers. You could have your "master" program simply change prepared source files and compile them. This would, however, heavily depend on your application scenario. Do your uses have a c++ compiler installed? Which one? Where does it live?